# converting table rows to json format

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 1500 rows in my table.

While converting table rows to json by the

query 
`select * from tblbook for json auto`;

only one row is converted to json.

Please help me. Comments are Appreciated

sample json data:

```
[    {
      "bid":0,
      "book_type":1,
      "book_id":"426128_1_En",
      "book_s50_due_dt":"2017-08-02T00:00:00",
      "book_s50_finish_dt":"2017-08-02T00:00:00",
      "book_s600_recd_dt":"2017-08-29T00:00:00",
      "book_s600_due_dt":"2017-08-28T00:00:00",
      "book_s600_finish_dt":"2017-08-29T00:00:00",
      "book_s650_recd_dt":"2017-08-29T00:00:00",
      "book_s650_due_dt":"2017-08-29T00:00:00",
      "book_s650_finish_dt":"2017-08-29T00:00:00",
      "book_cover_recd_dt":"2018-07-02T11:59:00",
      "book_cover_due_dt":"2018-07-05T11:59:00",
      "book_cover_recd_flag":false,
      "book_status_remarks":" 10-Succ 7\/20",
      "stage":"s200",
      "issue_pages":0,
      "book_ms_pages":0,
      "book_cover_pages":2,
      "book_blank_pages":0,
      "book_ce_pages":0,
      "book_inputrecdType":"Pdf",
      "book_processType":"Stapp",
      "book_copubname":"",
      "book_authcorr_status":0,
      "book_totalservice":2,
      "book_receiptType":"",
      "book_shortcutwf":1,
      "book_trichy_PE_tag":0,
      "book_trichy_CE_tag":0,
      "book_trichy_location":0,
      "book_trichy_art_location":0,
      "book_FastTrack":false,
      "book_Hold":false,
      "book_Withdrawn":false,
      "book_Project_Manager":"",
      "book_Spl_Instructions":true,
      "book_CreditLine":"",
      "book_Cust_Type":"LNCS ENGG",
      "book_arabic_pages":0,
      "book_roman_pages":0,
      "book_fm_elements":"",
      "book_bm_elements":"",
      "book_bw_figures_count":0,
      "book_color_figures_count":0,
      "book_scan_status":0
```

This was the out put when a ran above mentioned query.

Comment: why are u using select in mongodb, you must use db.tblbook.find()

Comment: I used this query in sql server for converting table data to json

Comment: you have to post question tag regarding sql server not mongodb

Comment: ok sorry. Help me in this question .Or should i change the tag

Comment: i have edited you question, you have to approve my edit

Comment: refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: i think you have to use caps---- FOR JSON AUTO

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that code with a test table and it worked just fine, my guess is that you have too many rows so to be sure you can try this work around:

Giving that the column "bid" is a primary key and doesn't have duplicates, you can try running this:

```
Select 'Select TOP 1 * from tblbook where bid = ' + cast(bid as varchar) + ' for json auto;' from tblbook
```

That code will generate queries and each converts a single row for each row of your table, all you have to do is copy paste and execute, before executing make sure to switch to "resaults in text" (shortcut Ctrl+T on SQL Server, then Ctrl+D to switch back to grid), This should give something like this (the example is with my test table, and yeah it's in frensh):

```
JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"Nom":1,"ProdId":100}]

(1 ligne affectée)

JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"Nom":1,"ProdId":300}]

(1 ligne affectée)

JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"Nom":1,"ProdId":500}]

(1 ligne affectée)

JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"Nom":2,"ProdId":600}]

(1 ligne affectée)
```

You can copy that to something like Notepad++ to erase the unwanted repeated text(like `(1 ligne affectée)` and the dashes) using replace function.

It's a lot of work but I hope this helps you get out of your problem.